# Build an iOS app & Node.js API simultaneously

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku

I'm building an iOS app that communicates to a Node.js API I'm also building. Locally, everything is ok, I've structured my iOS code in a way that I only declare the API base URL in one place (ie. 192.168.0.3:5000 - local).

However, you can imagine where I'm going with this.

Once I deploy the API to Heroku, what's the best way for me to manage the iOS side of things in regard to: 1. testing locally with the local API, 2. deploying the iOS app to the app store (ie. how do I tell it to use a different API URL?)

Any advice would be great on setting up a sane development environment for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XCode project, configure the "debug" version to use the local api and the "release" version to use the web api.

Comment: Sounds ideal. Still getting used to the lingo in iOS. Whereabouts would I find this in Xcode?

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/articles/basingbuildconfigurationsonconfigurationfiles.html

Comment: Cheers. I ended up going with a preprocessor macro that I set to a diff value for debug & release